# Most Popular Combination of Movies in a Ms-Access Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design

Table has two columns. The first is a person's name, the second a movie title.
Essentially the first table depicts each person's favorite movies.

What I am trying to accomplish in MS-Access is this.
To generate the top 10 combinations of 2 movie titles, ranked by number of students that have BOTH movie titles listed as their favorites.

The table is "FavoriteMovies"
First column which is student name is "ProfileID"
Second Column which is the movie title is "FavoriteMovie"

Each combination cant have the same movie twice and for each combination order doesnt matter, meaning Titanic & The Godfather = The Godfather & Titanic

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work, although I don't have Access to hand to test it:

```
Select Top 10
  fm1.FavoriteMovie As Movie1,
  fm2.FavoriteMovie As Movie2,
  Count(*) As TotalLikes
From
  FavoriteMovies fm1
    Inner Join
  FavoriteMovies fm2
    On fm1.ProfileID = fm2.ProfileID And
       fm1.FavoriteMovie < fm2.FavoriteMovie
Group By
  fm1.FavoriteMovie,
  fm2.FavoriteMovie
Order By
  3 Desc
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/YclT4.png what happened when i tried running the code. no idea why though?

Comment: @rbd246 Sorry, spelled the table name without an s on the end - have updated

Comment: Awesome! It works. Im new to this site so is there some way i reward you or something? Ive migrated from yahoo answers to here. This site is absolute gold.

Comment: Eventually you'll get enough points that you can tick the answer. There might be a time delay to start with, not entirely sure.

Comment: @rbd246 If you are happy with an answer you can accept it, you do not have to, but if you want to, just click the tick mark.